# Asp.net MVC 5 Ajax POST throws exception 404 (Not Found) after application is published

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

Everything works fine locally (When i run with localhost), But after i published to IIS and runs, it throws exception in browser console

> POST http://xx.xxx.x.x/Dashboard/FilterData 404 (Not Found)

Below is my code, I am using a button to call this javascript function

**VIEW - Index**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function btnFilterClick() {

        var txtFDate = $("#dpFrom");
        var txtTDate = $("#dpTo");
        var ddBranches = $("#ddBranches");
        var ddBrands = $("#ddBrands");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Dashboard/FilterData",
            data: '{FromDate: "' + txtFDate.val() + '", ToDate: "' + txtTDate.val() + '", SelectedBranches : "'+ ddBranches.val()+'", SelectedBrands : "'+ ddBrands.val()+'" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success:
                function (r)
                {
                    chartPurchaseVsSales.data.datasets[0].data = r.listSalesData;
                    chartPurchaseVsSales.data.datasets[1].data = r.listPurchaseData;
                    chartPurchaseVsSales.data.labels = r.xAxisNameForPurchaseAndSales;
                    chartPurchaseVsSales.update();


                }
        });


    }

    </script>
```

**Controller  - DashboardController**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult FilterData(DashboardModel modelX)
    {
        DashboardModel model = new DashboardModel();
        model.xAxisNameForPurchaseAndSales = new string[] { };
        model.xAxisNameForStock = new string[] { };



        *Skipped some codes to make it simple*

        return Json(model);

    }
```

Any idea whats wrong here ? I am newbie in web developments! Help Me!

Comment: What's the URL to the Index?

Comment: Dashboard/Index @freedomn-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed to `'@Url.Action("FilterData", "Dashboard")'` and it works fine! Thank you, guys.

Below is my code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("FilterData", "Dashboard")',
        data: '{FromDate: "' + txtFDate.val() + '", ToDate: "' + txtTDate.val() + '", SelectedBranches : "'+ ddBranches.val()+'", SelectedBrands : "'+ ddBrands.val()+'" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function (r)
            {
                chartPurchaseVsSales.data.datasets[0].data = r.listSalesData;
                chartPurchaseVsSales.data.datasets[1].data = r.listPurchaseData;
                chartPurchaseVsSales.data.labels = r.xAxisNameForPurchaseAndSales;
                chartPurchaseVsSales.update();


            }
    });
```

Comment: URL is fine when i put it inside single quotes (From source ), otherwise it shows exception invalid regular expression

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the path is `/dashboard/filterdata` or something else such as `/yourapp/dashboard/filterdata`

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, it's the correct answer that the other two answers, while hinting at, do not provide with specific/*correct* details.

Comment: Actually, I gave the idea along with code (Just missing the quotes). So the OP just tests and give me feedback instead of answer his own question.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

You can change from `url: "/Dashboard/FilterData",` like below

```
url: '@Url.Action("FilterData", "Dashboard")'
```

**Solution 2**

In HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("FilterData", "Dashboard")" id='url' />
```

In Jquery

```
url: $("#url").val()
```

Comment: Or, more specifically: `url: '@Url.Action("FilterData", "Dashboard")'` as long as you keep this in your .cshtml and don't put it in a .js

Comment: freedomn-m ,  could you please show me one snippet ? I got exception *Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags*

Comment: @Phong my point being that you **must wrap it in quotes** if you put it in the javascript, otherwise you get invalid javascript and probably where *"invalid regular expression flags"* is happening - ie your code: `url: /dashboard/filterdata` required code: `url: '/dashboard/filterdata'` (after processing)

Comment: Yes single quotes required when we use this inside javascript

Comment: No - that would output as:  `url: "'" + /dashboard/filterdata + "'"` - which is not a valid string

Comment: @Lazy Programer Please check my answer and give me your feedback.

Comment: Phong, I have checked it and i wrote my own solution which i have posted as answer here

Comment: There are two wrong answers in what should be a simple answer.  `url: "'" + @Url...` will give a javascript error and `url: "'" + $("#url").val() + "'"` will generate an invalid url.  You need to wrap `@Url.Action` in quotes, not add quotes to the url if you're getting it via javascript from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the URL in your ajax request to 
**URL: '/YourAppName/Controller/ActionResult'**, after publishing it on IIS. This is why the URL should never be hardcoded. You can use a hidden field in your razor page and populate the URL like @Url.Action("FilterData", "Dashboard") and read it from there. I hope it helps.